# Creating text string on mouse click in Java-Swing?

Tags: java, swing

Using swing, trying to make the text "Mouse is Clicked" appear on the screen for 2 seconds whenever I click the mouse.

This is what I have so far.

```
String s = "";
int timeDelay = 30;
public void paintFrame(Graphics g) {
        g.drawString(s, 100, 100);

        if (timeDelay>0) {
            timeDelay--;

        }

        if(isMouseClicked()) {
            String s = "Mouse is clicked";
            timeDelay = 30;
            return;
        }

        String s = "";
}
```

Nothing is showing up when I click, can't seem to figure out why.

Comment: The outcome here looks dependent on how paintFrame is called and how often, and isMouseClicked()'s implementation, so you will probably need to show that code and explain what you think it does.

Comment: You want to look into action listeners, that will help a lot.  I would implement an action listener for the mouseclick that put the string on the screen, waited 2 seconds, then erased it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call g.drawString()  inside if condition for  isMouseClicked(). Also inside the if condition for isMouseClicked() you are creating a new local parameter String s(not sure if you want to do that). You cna try the following piece of code.

```
 if(isMouseClicked()) {
        s = "Mouse is clicked";
        timeDelay = 30;
        g.drawString(s, 100, 100);
  }
 else{
      s = "";
 }
 g.drawString(s, 100, 100);
```

Comment: Try the modified code. This happens becuase you are not calling draw for teh case when mouse is not clicked. Also how are you using timeDelay ?

Comment: This works now, although it is not lasting for two seconds. Everything inside paintFrame runs 15 times per second, right? timeDelay is 30 for two seconds.

Comment: @jzacharia I am not sure how timeDelay is being used on your code, I cannot comment on it unless i see the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not disappearing for whatever reason, you could use the tertiary operator for a quick fix. Set's the string depending on the isMouseClicked() boolean

```
s = isMouseClicked() ? "Mouse is clicked" : "";
g.drawString(s,100,100);
```

Comment: The question is about making text appear for two seconds, not only when the mouse is pressed. Your answer doesn't help with the timing aspect of the question. Also, it's spelled "ternary", not "tertiary" :)

Comment: I assumed the isMouseClicked() was used to determine whether or not the text should appear but I guess it would make more sense that it is just mouse clicked. Spelling error was my fault